How to check Pandas dataframe for a greek character
I have a dataframe created from an XLSX spreadsheet that has Ω in a cell. (The character shown here is generated by typing Alt-234)
df.unit.iloc[1] returns 'Ω'
But
df.unit.iloc[1] == 'Ω' and 'Ω' in df.unit.iloc[1] both return False
I've tried using '\u03A9' with the same results.  What am I missing?
(Python 3.11)

Out of curiosity, what is the result of omega = df.unit.iloc[1] followed by df.unit.iloc[1] == omega ? I'm wondering if your issue is related to some encoding problem.

also what the result of print(df.unit.iloc[1])?

The omega experiment 'worked' (came back True).

The Print check returned the Ω character without tick marks.

But omega == 'Ω' returns false.

Try this: print(df.unit.iloc[1].encode('utf-8')) and print('Ω'.encode('utf-8')). My guess is the hex values differ from the omega character you copy/pasted

Somehow your code works in my case.
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'unit':['A', 'Ω']})
df.unit.iloc[1] == 'Ω'

Output from the last line is True.
Could you please provide DataFrame sample?
Including  output from the following command df.unit.to_list()[:3] in the question should help as well.
As you might be searching for 'Ω' in the adjacent index or column.

My guess is the OP's omega character 'Ω' is encoded differently than the version it is being compared to.

@h0r53 I think you are right.

It sounds odd that there is a single isolated Greek letter in your data. You haven't indicated what the data is, so I'm guessing here, but I suspect it isn't a Greek letter, but a confusable of that character.
Try
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'unit':['A', 'Ω']})
df1.unit.iloc[1] == '\u2126'
# 0    False
# 1     True
# Name: unit, dtype: bool

or if a number and unit scenario:
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'unit':['A', '25Ω']})
df2.unit.str.contains('\u2126')
# 0    False
# 1     True
# Name: unit, dtype: bool

or
'\u2126' in df2.unit.iloc[1]
# True

Where \u2126 is Ω (Ohm sign).
See
import icu
from icu import CanonicalIterator
ci = CanonicalIterator('Ω')
print([char for char in ci])
# ['Ω', 'Ω']

although a full list of characters that resolve to Omega under normalisation to NFKC:
 ‎33C0 SQUARE K OHM
 ‎33C1 SQUARE M OHM
 ‎03A9 GREEK CAPITAL LETTER OMEGA
 ‎2126 OHM SIGN
 ‎1D6C0 MATHEMATICAL BOLD CAPITAL OMEGA
 ‎1D6FA MATHEMATICAL ITALIC CAPITAL OMEGA
 ‎1D734 MATHEMATICAL BOLD ITALIC CAPITAL OMEGA
 ‎1D76E MATHEMATICAL SANS-SERIF BOLD CAPITAL OMEGA
 ‎1D7A8 MATHEMATICAL SANS-SERIF BOLD ITALIC CAPITAL OMEGA


The data is measured resistance values.  The ohms sign is in the Units column.  I was using \u03A9 for the character.  I'll try \u2126 when I get back to that project.  I'm also considering hand entering the character (Alt-234) in the spreadsheet and seeing if that works.  I could also, of course, replace it with "Ohms" which is normal usage.  But that would be cheating, right? ;-)
